# SQL - Trying to add variable into string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a store procedure where I pass a path to the file like:

```
EXEC spMyPathFile         
@PFile = 'C:\TFiles\Paths\Test_1.1_Version.txt'
```

What I'd like to do it loop through and be able to pass a number of versions of the file like 1.1 and 1.2 etc using:

```
DECLARE @intLp INT  
DECLARE @a varchar(2)  
SET @intLp = 1 WHILE (@intLp <2) 
BEGIN  IF @intLp = 1  BEGIN
        SET @a = '1.1'
        END
      ELSE IF @intLp = 2
      BEGIN
        SET @a = '1.2'
    END

EXEC spMyPathFile         
@PFile = 'C:\TFiles\Paths\Test_'+@a+'_Version.txt'       
SET @intLp = @intLp + 1 
END
```

For some reason I get "Incorrect syntax near '+'." which is just before the @a. I'm obviously not joining my variable to my string properly.

Could someone give me an example of how this should look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
EXEC spMyPathFile         
@PFile = 'C:\TFiles\Paths\Test_'+@a+'_Version.txt'
```

to

```
declare @FileName varchar(100) = 'C:\TFiles\Paths\Test_' + @a + '_Version.txt' 
EXEC spMyPathFile         
@PFile = @FileName
```

---

### Edit:

From MSDN - [Specify Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189260.aspx)

> The parameter values supplied with a procedure call must be constants or a variable; a function name cannot be used as a parameter value. Variables can be user-defined or system variables such as @@spid.